# Weak equality equation with a negative fractional Sobolev space.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, trace, fractional-sobolev-spaces

## Sobolev Preamble

For $N\geqslant 2$, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a connected, bounded, open set with Lipschitz continuous boundary $\partial \Omega$.

Let the space $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ denote the Sobolev–Slobodeckij space (or fractional Sobolev space) defined by the seminorm

\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}^2:= \|f\|^2_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}+ \oint\limits_{\partial \Omega}\oint\limits_{\partial \Omega} \dfrac{|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y})|}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^{N}}dS_{\mathbf{x}}dS_{\mathbf{y}}.
\end{equation}
Let $H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ denote the dual of the space $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, with associated norm
\begin{equation}
\|g\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)}:= \sup\limits_{v \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)\setminus \{0\}}\dfrac{\left<g, v \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}}{\|v\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}}
\end{equation}
EDIT: To clarify $\left<g, v \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$ is understood in the sense,
\begin{equation}
\left<g, v \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} := \oint\limits_{\partial \Omega} gv \ dS_{\mathbf{x}},
\end{equation}
the $g\in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is the functional that acts upon $v\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$.

## Weak equation

For a given $g \in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, I wish to understand the solutions $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ to the following equation
\begin{equation}
\left< g, \phi \right>_{H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)} = \left< Tu, \phi \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}, \quad \forall \phi \in H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega),
\end{equation}
where the bounded surjective map $T:H^1(\Omega)\rightarrow H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ is the trace operator.

## Problem

I wish to understand if I could express the trace of $u$ explicitly in terms of $g$. For example, if I set $\phi=g$ then I deduce that
\begin{equation}
\|g\|^2_{H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega)}= \sup\limits_{\|v\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}=1}\left<g, v \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}^2 = \left< Tu, g \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}
\end{equation}
Thus, we have that
\begin{equation}
\sup\limits_{\|v\|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}=1}\left<g, v\left<g, v \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}-Tu \right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}=0
\end{equation}
In a certain sense, one could view the trace of $u$ as equal to the projection of $g$ onto $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$. However, I am unsure how to generalise this to $\phi\neq g$. Do I require a more restrictive test function space for $\phi$?

Comment: I suggest being more precise about your function spaces until you are comfortable with what's going on. Note: $H^{-1/2}$ does not come with a natural embedding into $L^2$; indeed, from the definition, it's not even clear that it is a function space. The norm you wrote down for it does not make sense ($g$ need not be in $L^2$). The relationship between $Tu$ and $g$ is that $g \in H^{-1/2}$ is the functional that acts on $H^{1/2}$ functions $v$ by $g(v) = \int v Tu$.

Comment: @user378654 Thank you for the response and I apologise for the poor notation. I used $<g,v>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$ as shorthand for $<g,v>_{H^{-1/2}(\partial \Omega),H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)}$ which is equal to $\oint_{\partial \Omega}gv dS_{\mathbf{x}}$. The space $H^{-1/2}$ is the dual of $H^{1/2}$, and therefore is the set of linear functionals over $H^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner product in $H^{1/2}$ is given by
$$(f,g)_{H^{1/2}}=\int_{\partial \Omega}fg\,dS+\int_{\partial\Omega}\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y))}{|x-y|^N}dS_xdS_y$$
By Riesz representation theorem, given a linear continuous function $L:H^{1/2}\to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique function $f\in H^{1/2}$ such that $$L(\phi)=(f,\phi)_{H^{1/2}}$$ for all $\phi\in H^{1/2}$. Let’s write $L=L_f$ for later.

So in the definition of norm in $H^{-1/2}$ you cannot take the $L^2$ norm. The norm of $L$ is
$$\sup_{v\in H^{1/2}\setminus\{0\}}\frac{L(v)}{\|v\|_{H^{1/2}}}= \sup_{v\in H^{1/2}\setminus\{0\}}\frac{(f,v)_{H^{1/2}}}{\|v\|_{H^{1/2}}}$$

The EDIt is not correct.

Now, it is not clear what you are asking. You  fix $L\in H^{-1/2}$ and you want to solve
$$(L,M)_{H^{-1/2}}=L(Tu)$$ for every $M$ in the dual?
If $L,M\in H^{-1/2}$, we have that $L=L_f$ and $M=M_h$ for some $f$ and $h$ in $H^{1/2}$ and their inner product
$$(L,M)_{H^{-1/2}}=(f,h)_{H^{1/2}}$$
[The dual $H'$ of a Hilbert Space $H$ is a Hilbert Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555914/the-dual-h-of-a-hilbert-space-h-is-a-hilbert-space)
So what yo are asking is
$$(f,h)_{H^{1/2}}=(h,Tu)_{H^{1/2}}$$ for all $h\in H^{1/2}$? Then the only solution is $f=Tu$, so $ u$ is any function whose trace is $f$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering this question.  I am not qualified to evaluate the quality of this answer, so I am waiting on @mathematurgist to accept this answer or give rationale as to why he doesn't think it addresses his question.  If he does not do anything within the next day or two I will award the bounty regardless.  I apologize about the delay.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, but just to clarify the rational regarding 5th equation

$$ (f,h)_{H^{1/2}} = (L,M)_{H^{-1/2}} $$
May I ask for a justification of this? 
Also, I am worried that there is a miscommunication, regarding my notation. Let $P(Tu)$ denote the action of $\phi$ on $Tu$, I am asking for a given $G \in H^{-1/2}$, 

$$(G,P)_{H^{-1/2}} = P(Tu), \quad \forall P \in H^{-1/2} $$

Which is different from the expression you give in your 4th equation, where you fix P (or L as you denote). Is the same methodology applicable? Sorry about the delay, I was in France for 3 days.

Comment: The justification is in the link just below the formula. 
As for your comment. It is the same. By Riesz representation theorem, every $P$ in the dual can be represented as the inner product with some function in $H^{1/2}$.

Comment: Writing $P(Tu)$ for every $P$ in the dual is the same as writing $(h,Tu)_{H^{1/2}}$ for every $h\in H^{1/2}$ because every $P$ in $H^{-1/2}$ has the form $P(\phi)=(h,\phi)_{H^{1/2}}$ for some $h\in H^{1/2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer this has solved my question. I hope you have a wonderful day.